# Why setter/getter definition in .assign object merge doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a sort of inheritance in my JS app.
Here is what I have:

```
function FooObject(param1, param2) {
   this._param1= param1;
   this._param2= param2;
}

Object.defineProperties(FooObject.prototype, {
    param1:
    {
        get: function () { return this._param1; },

        set: function (val) { this._param1= val; }
    }
});
```

Above is a "base class", all right?

Then I define another object, which extends the FooObject and adds more properties, by merging:

```
  function FooObjectA(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    FooObject.call(this, param1, someVal);
    this._param2= param2;
    this._param3= param3;
    this._param4= param4;
  }

 FooObjectA.prototype = Object.assign(Object.create(FooObject.prototype),
 {
     constructor: FooObjectA,

    param2:
    {
        get: function () { return this._param2; },

        set: function (val) { this._param2= val; }
    },

   param3:
    {
        get: function () { return this._param3; },

        set: function (val) { this._param3 = val; }
    }
```

});

Now, if I am trying to get param3, for example:

```
  var fooInstance = new FooObjectA();
  
  var p = fooInstance .param3;
```

then `p` doesn't hold the value of _param3 but refers to the getter method.

Then I tried this approach:

```
  Object.defineProperties(FooObjectA.prototype, {
  {
   
    param2:
    {
        get: function () { return this._param2; },

        set: function (val) { this._param2= val; }
    },

   param3:
    {
        get: function () { return this._param3; },

        set: function (val) { this._param3 = val; }
    }
```

});

And now it returns the value from the getter ok. I am pretty new to JavaScript and would like to understand why it doesn't work when I put getters/setters into .assign.. create... , because logically I can't see why those getters are not merged with the prototype of FooObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` reads the **value** of the property (calling the getter) and stores that value on the target object as a simple data property.

If you want to copy the getter/setter definition, you'll need to implement your own function that checks the property descriptor (`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, "propName")`) and handles creating a getter/setter property on the target.

> then p doesn't hold the value of _param3 but reference to the getter method.

That's a separate problem. You're passing an object to `Object.assign` expecting it to be interpreted the way `Object.defineProperties` does:

```
FooObjectA.prototype = smartAssign(Object.create(FooObject.prototype), {
    constructor: FooObjectA,
    param2: {
        get: function() {
            return this._param2;
        },
        set: function(val) {
            this._param2 = val;
        }
    },
    param3: {
        get: function() {
            return this._param3;
        },
        set: function(val) {
            this._param3 = val;
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to use that format, you need to call `Object.defineProperties` to interpret it:

```
FooObjectA.prototype = smartAssign(Object.defineProperties(Object.create(FooObject.prototype), {
// --------------------------------^
    constructor: FooObjectA,
    param2: {
        get: function() {
            return this._param2;
        },
        set: function(val) {
            this._param2 = val;
        }
    },
    param3: {
        get: function() {
            return this._param3;
        },
        set: function(val) {
            this._param3 = val;
        }
    }
})); // <=== Added )
```

Here's a quick sketch of a function (using ES5 syntax) that does it; you'll need to test and harden it, most likely:

```
var hasOwn = function(obj, prop) { // Paranoia, in case an object overrides it
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
};
function smartAssign(target) {
    var n, source, key;
    for (n = 1; n < arguments.length; ++n) {
        source = arguments[n];
        for (key in source) {
            if (hasOwn(source, key)) {
                Object.defineProperty(target, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key));
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Live Example using that and with the other problem fixed:

```js
var hasOwn = function(obj, prop) {
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
};
function smartAssign(target) {
    var n, source, key;
    for (n = 1; n < arguments.length; ++n) {
        source = arguments[n];
        for (key in source) {
            if (hasOwn(source, key)) {
                Object.defineProperty(target, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key));
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}

function FooObject(param1, param2) {
    this._param1 = param1;
    this._param2 = param2;
}

Object.defineProperties(FooObject.prototype, {
    param1: {
        get: function() {
            return this._param1;
        },
        set: function(val) {
            this._param1 = val;
        }
    }
});

function FooObjectA(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    FooObject.call(this, param1, 42);
    this._param2 = param2;
    this._param3 = param3;
    this._param4 = param4;
}

FooObjectA.prototype = smartAssign(Object.defineProperties(Object.create(FooObject.prototype), {
    constructor: FooObjectA,
    param2: {
        get: function() {
            return this._param2;
        },
        set: function(val) {
            this._param2 = val;
        }
    },
    param3: {
        get: function() {
            return this._param3;
        },
        set: function(val) {
            this._param3 = val;
        }
    }
}));

var fooInstance = new FooObjectA("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4");
console.log(fooInstance.param1);
console.log(fooInstance.param3);
```

Comment: @MichaelIV: Turned out there was a second problem (which explains part of your question that I didn't immediately get); updated to explain the second problem and post a sketch of a solution to the first.

Comment: Well,looks like JS can be quite versatile in ways of implementing things )) I guess I will go with Object.DefineProperties() as it is much cleaner and readable. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @MichaelIV: My pleasure. :-) I'll also point out that ES2015 added `class` syntax, which can be transpiled for older environments, which makes this stuff a lot more concise and less error-prone (while still retaining the same prototypical nature). Happy coding!